# IMPDP and EXPDP bat file

Tags: oracle, batch-file, datapump

I have a dump file located on the data_pump_directory on server "A" for example. I want to make a bat file on my local laptop that prompts me for the dump file name and import data pump to server "A".

I tried and succeeded to make other bat files that create drop and give grants to users (on server A), but the IMPDP and the EXPDP bats don't work.

My bat file looks like the following:

```
set /p dumpfile= enter dump name:
C:
cd /

IMPDP system/******@(DESCRIPTION=(ADDRESS=(PROTOCOL=TCP)(Host=**.*.**.***)(Port=1521))(CONNECT_DATA=(SID=****))) DUMPFILE="%dumpfile%.dmp" LOGFILE="%dumpfile%.log"  SCHEMAS=('****') DIRECTORY=DATA_PUMP_DIR CONTENT=ALL  TABLE_EXISTS_ACTION=REPLACE

pause
```

Comment: Maybe it would be helpful to post your batch file? You can [edit] your question to include them. Why don't they work? Are you getting any error messages?

Comment: don't work means exactly what? Do you have an error message?